# How to install latest casperJS version on CircleCI via yml file?

Tags: continuous-integration, casperjs, circleci

I start to use circeCI. I need to run my casperJS test automatically. But today CircleCI install 1.0 casperjs ver, but i need 1.1. version, the latest. How to explain in yml file, that i need the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use npm to install casperjs. You just need to add the command to the dependencies.post section of your circle.yml. Your circle.yml will look like:

```
dependencies:
  post:
    - npm install -g casperjs@1.1.0-beta3
```

Alternatively, if you're already using a package.json, then you can put casperjs there and CircleCI will install it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own version as part of the build: see https://circleci.com/docs/installing-custom-software

Alternatively, contact support and we can install it for you :)